# Helpfulnes of reviews: Why does Amazon or Steam not show the number of unhelpful ratings of a review?

Tags: user-expectation, e-commerce, feedback

From my own experience I found the ratio between helpful and unhelpful reviews to be hugely important to assess how much I could trust / consider a review. I noticed that Amazon and also the [Steam Store](https://store.steampowered.com/) removed this ratio some time in the last 12 months after using it for years. Instead they only show the "helpful" number. You can still vote "unhelpful" and as a user I would expect that my feedback does something but in the current system it is not shown anywhere.

[image: helpful unhelpful]

For a project I might need to implement something similar so **I am trying to understand why they changed a system that worked for years**.

A Google Search does not offer an official statement from Amazon or Steam why they changed this. I found forum discussions where users made assumptions but noone seems to be certain. From the [Steam blog](https://steamcommunity.com/games/593110/announcements/detail/2666556941788470579) (text search: "Taking a closer look") I found out they might have done this in order to combat review manipulation. But this reasoning refers to how they order and filter relevant reviews. Not how they show information about a review.

Do you have sources / insights that explains why they changed this?

Comment: What happens to the when you click on either button?

Comment: I've noticed the "Not Helpful" buttons are sometimes missing for some items.

Comment: Questions asking 'why did company X do {thing}' are ones we can only speculate on, unless the person who actually made the decision at that company happens to be a member here. Your best option is to post on a specific support forum from that company rather than somewhere like StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

Because they want more people to post ratings, and if potential commenters know that an unhelpful count would be shown next to their rating/comments, they would less likely to post a review. The unhelpful count is a form of criticism, in general, you don't want to make your customers feel criticized.